# HOW TO use or query get request using title with REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to send req such as `http://website.com/vdo.php?vdo=my-first-vido-is-here` insted of using id in url such as `http://website.com/vdo.php?vdo=22`

```
 // $title is from database table
 $title=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $title);
```

I tried using

```
<a href=http://website.com/vdo.php?vdo=$title> click here </a>
```

and recived request as

```
if(isset($_GET['vdo']))
    $vdo=$_GET['vdo'];
    $get_v="SELECT * FROM `vdo` WHERE `title`=$vdo";
```

how can i receive request or how can i use regexp for `title`
as $title not matching with database `title`

Comment: or is there any other send get request method for using title inside URL??

Comment: You should add a column to our database table called "slug" where you store the result of your `preg_replace()`. Then you can simply search for it. Just remember that you should use Prepared Statements with bound parameters when querying data from the database using user inputs. If not, you will be wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: Another way (and more common) is to have the slug in the actual URL itself: `example.com/some-page-name`. Look for some router-library for that (there's many to choose from if you do some research).

Answer (score 0):

I think is because of your title have some special character. You can solve this problem by set **PARAMS**

Example:

```
if(isset($_GET['vdo']))
{
   $vdo=$_GET['vdo'];
   $get_v="SELECT * FROM `vdo` WHERE `title`=?";
   $con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb','username','password',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)); 
   $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute(array($vdo));
}
```

You can find out more example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)